# Using the current object instance in a Moq callback

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I want to create a stub using Moq that has a function Foo that will push the stub instance onto a list passed as a parameter. I can use the `Callback<>()` method to capture the list, but I don't have access to the stub instance from there, do I?

This is what I've got so far:

```
var stubPattern = new Mock<IBar>();
stubPattern.Setup(stub => stub.Foo(It.IsAny<List<IBar>>()))
    .Callback<List<IBar>>(list => list.Add(stubInstance); // stubInstance not valid
```

Is it possible to do something like this in Moq?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean to get the mock instance itself, you can use `Object` property.

```
stubPattern.Setup(stub => stub.Foo(It.IsAny<List<IBar>>()))
           .Callback<List<IBar>>(list => list.Add(stubPattern.Object);
```

Comment: Oh! I had naively assumed Object created a new instance every time, not produced the same instance over and over. Thanks.